# Search in vuejs with laravel backend api

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel 5.6 as the api for the backend and vuejs for the frontend spa application. And https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable package for search which worked well in my previous projects where i used blade templating engine.

I'm new to vuejs and im learning how to do things and im stuck at a point where im confused how to use laravel search on the frontend.

What i did previously in other projects where i used blade for the frontend

In my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $start_search = microtime('s');
        $searchterm = $request->input('search');
        if($request->has('search')){
           $results =  Web::search($searchterm)->paginate(10);
         } else {
          $results =  Web::latest()->paginate(10);
         }
        $stop_search = microtime('s');
        $time_search = ($stop_search - $start_search);
        return view('search.index', compact('results', 'searchterm', 'time_search'));
    }
```

And in my view

```
<small>{{$results->total()}} results found for "<em class="b-b b-warning">{{$searchterm}}</em>" in {{$time_search}} seconds</small>
@forelse ($results as $result)
        <div class="mb-3">
          <a href="{{ url($result->url) }}" class="text-primary clear h-1x">{{$result->meta_title}} <span class="badge badge-pill primary">{{$result->rank}}</span></a>
          <span class="text-success clear h-1x">{{$result->url}}</span>
          <span class="h-2x">{{$result->meta_description}}</span>
        </div>
      @empty
        No Results Found
      @endforelse
      <div class="pt-2 pagination-sm">
          {{ $results->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4') }}
      </div>
```

This code worked well where i was able to search and display results properly along with search time.

Now i want to do the same with laravel api and vuejs frontend. So this is what i tried

```
public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $start_search = microtime('s');
            $searchterm = $request->input('search');
            if($request->has('search')){
               $results =  Web::search($searchterm)->paginate(10);
             } else {
              $results =  Web::latest()->paginate(10);
             }
            $stop_search = microtime('s');
            $time_search = ($stop_search - $start_search);
            return WebResource::collection($results);
        }
```

I created a collection resource for the same.

**Question 1**. My question related to controller code, how to return $searchterm and $time_search so that i can use them on the frontend.

In my vue component, i tried with my learning till now

```
<template>
other code..
<div class="mb-3" v-for="result in results" :key="result.results">
  <router-link :to="result.url" class="text-primary clear h-1x"> {{ result.meta_title }} </router-link>
  <span class="h-2x">{{ result.meta_description }}</span>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  layout: 'main',

  computed: mapGetters({
      locale: 'lang/locale',
      authenticated: 'auth/check'
  }),

  metaInfo () {
    return { title: this.$t('searchpagetitle') }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
        results: [],
        title: window.config.appName
    }
  },

  watch: {
    locale: function (newLocale, oldLocale) {
      this.getResults()
    }
  },

  mounted() {
      console.log(this.locale)
      this.getResults ()
  },

  methods: {
    getResults() {
      var app = this;
      axios.get('/api/web')
        .then(response => {
          // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
          this.results = response.data.data
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Question 2**: My second question related to vuejs, how to create a search form and render results according to the search and with proper search url ending with ?searchterm=searchkeywords in my case.

When i used blade i used the normal html form with action url so that it rendered results. Also i used $searchterm to use the same search terms to search in other routes like images, videos.
I just used {{ url('/images?searchterm='.$searchterm) }} in the href so that when user clicks on it, it renders results of all images with the same keyword just like google. And also used placeholder as "enter your search" and value as "{{$searchterm}}" so that the search term stayed in the search form too.

I want to know how to do all the same in vuejs.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to append the search keyword in request URL of API in frontend. So your request url will be like

```
axios.get('/api/web?searchterm='+this.searchterm)
```

And in your Laravel controller, you can get this value by using **Input::get()** , so your code to get searchterm will be

```
$searchterm = Input::get('searchterm');
```

And then you can fetch your data on basis of **$searchterm** variable.

Comment: And what about the form in vuejs. How to make it so that the page doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: You can use VUEjs on click function **v-on:click** to call your function **getResults()** function or call your function **getResults()** using **@submit** in form attribute like **<b-form @submit="getResults" >**

Comment: Wonderful! One final question is my question 1. How to return results, searchterm and search_time  in api controller code. I tried as array it does not show anything

Comment: I think you need to simply return ** compact('results', 'searchterm', 'time_search')** and see what your **response.data** have in response at your API call. You have to debug it by simply returning one response at first and then by compacting multiple values. in compact. Always try to see what you have in your response.data.